# Gson stackOverflown when deserializing Android Retrofit

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit2

I'm using retrofit2 coupled with Gson to consume API Rest point.
I have a CarOption model :

```
public class CarOption {

private String              name;
private String              label;
private boolean             isActive;
private String              type;
private Integer             onglet;
private Integer             position;
private List<CarOptionData> data;
private View                view;
```

and a CarForm model :

```
public class CarForm {

// DEBUG
private static final String TAG = CarForm.class.getName();

private ArrayList<CarOption>        fields = new ArrayList<>();
private static CarOptionComparator  coc = new CarOptionComparator();

private static ArrayList<CarOption> tab0 = null;
private static ArrayList<CarOption> tab1 = null;
private static ArrayList<CarOption> tab2 = null;
private static ArrayList<CarOption> tab3 = null;

public static void downloadCarForm(final Context context, final IRequestResponseListener cb) {
    Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitSingleton.getInstance();

    IWebServiceApi apiService = retrofit.create(IWebServiceApi.class);
    Call<CarForm>   call = apiService.getCarForm(User.getAccessToken());
    call.enqueue(new Callback<CarForm>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<CarForm> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            int statusCode = response.code();
            if (statusCode == 200 || statusCode == 201) {
                CarForm carForm = response.body(); // STACKOVERFLOWN ERROR FROM GSON
                carForm.unCrashOnglet(carForm.fields);
                Collections.sort(carForm.fields, coc);
                CarForm.setTab0(createTab(context, carForm.getFields(), 0));
                CarForm.setTab1(createTab(context, carForm.getFields(), 1));
                CarForm.setTab2(createTab(context, carForm.getFields(), 2));
                CarForm.setTab3(createTab(context, carForm.getFields(), 3));
                if (cb != null)
                    cb.onSuccess();
```

I have a stackoverflown error when Gson try to deserialize my object. I read about a possible error caused by a reference to a parent object, but I don't have it. Can't see where the error comes from.
It might be linked to the "tab" arrayList attributes as it was working before I created them.

Here's the error :

```
W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:334)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:358)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:155)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:97)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:407)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getFieldAdapter(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:136)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.access$100(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:49)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.<init>(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:106)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:105)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:161)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:97)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:407)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getFieldAdapter(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:136)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.access$100(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:49)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.<init>(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:106)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:105)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:161)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:97)
 W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:407)
```

Do you have any Idea on this issue ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you might want to move `private List<CarOptionData> data;` into `CarForm`

Comment: I think you have a circular dependency in your models. A circular dependency is when you have `A` referencing `B` which references `A` again. It would be more useful if you post all the model classes, related to the `CarForm`

Comment: What is the View class in this context?

Comment: Thanks all
Blackbelt : cal you elaborate ? It previously worked (before I added the other ArrayLists).

DanailAlexiev : I read about that but couldn't find one. Apart from CarOptionData which simply contains two attributes : id and name, I have no class relatied to my problem.

MuchOverflow: after I populate my tab0, tab1, etc. I generate a Android view according to some of the CarOption properties. So it is a simple android View item.

Comment: Well, I changed the View Attribute inside CarOption to an Object attribute and that solved it.

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments :

```
public class CarOption {
...
private View                view;
```

became :

```
public class CarOption {
...
private Object                view;
```

which solved my problem. Then I cast it back to a View when I need to access it.

Comment: I don't really know why so if someone could give an explanation. Maybe the View class has a circular dependency that causes this overflown.

Comment: That's weird... Thanks, I thought I was loosing my mind after a few hours of debugging.